# generate unique id like QUOTE_1,QUOTE_2 etc

Tags: php

Can anybody help me on how to generate a unique id like `QUOTE_1`, `QUOTE_2` etc.

I have tried `uniqid()` function. But it's giving a unique id with the current time.

```
public static function getQuoteNo()
{
    global $count;
    $GLOBALS['count'] = $GLOBALS['count']+1;
    $quoteno = 'QUOTE_'.$GLOBALS['count'];

    return $quoteno;
}
```

I have tried this function. But every time I am getting `QUOTE_1`.

Comment: where the $GLOBALS['count'] value is coming from;

Comment: Define better how "unique" the id needs to be and in what context it's used. Don't you have a database with an auto incrementing id in it? Is there any sort of *storage* that unique ids can be checked against?

Comment: @deceze Autoincremented value must be concatenated with QUOTE_

Comment: How about you just have the autoincrement id in the database and whenever you need to display it somewhere, you concatenate it with `QUOTE_`?

Answer (score -1):

The below finction will generate a unique code with respect to your count value

```
public static function getQuoteNo()
{
  global $count;
  $unique = time() + sprintf("%06d",(microtime(true) - floor(microtime(true))) * $count);
  $GLOBALS['count']=$GLOBALS['count']+1;
  $quoteno='QUOTE_'.$unique;
  return $quoteno;
}
```

Comment: I want it to be QUOTE_1,QUOTE_2,QUOTE_3,.. the series.

Comment: @Jaya Try saving count value in session once